# How to show Django page with VenoBox?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

[Portfolio page, each post have its detailed page that is accessible by clicking on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4DkM.jpg)

[Need the content of the detailed post page in the grey container but it's displayed over it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haLtf.png)

That's how I link it from each portfolio post

`<a href="{% url 'work' work.id %}" data-vbtype="ajax" class="venobox" title="Portfolio Details"></a>`

The detailed page code extended with template.html, where venobox css,js and jquery linked.

```
{% extends "template.html" %}

{% block content %}  

<main id="main">

    <!-- ======= Portfolio Details ======= -->
    <div id="portfolio-details" class="portfolio-details">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-8 ">
            <h2 class="portfolio-title">{{work.title}}</h2>
            <div class="owl-carousel portfolio-details-carousel">
            {% for image in work.images %}        
              <img src="{{image}}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            {% endfor %}

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 portfolio-info">
            <ul>
              <li><strong>Category</strong>: {{work.work_type}}</li>
              <li><strong>Project tools</strong>: {{work.tools}}</li>
              <li><strong>Project date</strong>: {{work.created}}</li>
              <li><strong>Project URL</strong>: <a href="{{work.link}}">{{work.link}}</a></li>
            </ul>

            <p>
              {{work.description}}
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div><!-- End Portfolio Details -->

  </main><!-- End #main --> 
{% endblock content %}`
```

Pls, help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is simply concerning the fact that the content is displayed over it instead of within then you can alter the values of the `venoBox`.

Custom settings, See [here](https://veno.es/venobox/) for more configurable options.

```
$('.venobox_custom').venobox({
    framewidth : '400px',                            // default: ''
    frameheight: '300px',                            // default: ''
    border     : '10px',                             // default: '0'
    bgcolor    : '#5dff5e',                          // default: '#fff'
    titleattr  : 'data-title',                       // default: 'title'
    numeratio  : true,                               // default: false
    infinigall : true,                               // default: false
    share      : ['facebook', 'twitter', 'download'] // default: []
});
```

You can also use `CSS` to set the badly positioned content to wherever you want on the page.

Comment: Thank you, very much.